# flutter_graphql with AWS

Tags: flutter, graphql

can anyone help me to configuring flutter_graphql package for aws-graphql with aws-cognito as Auth instead of api-key.

`final AuthLink authLink = AuthLink(
    getToken: () async => 'Bearer <YOUR_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN>',
);`

I can't understand how do I configure it with aws-cognito. I know I have to use aws_cognito_identity_pool_id. but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

use amazon_cognito_identity_dart_2 flutter package to create session and then get JWTtoken.

`final token = session.getAccessToken().getJwtToken(); 
//session from amazon_cognito_identity_dart_2

final AuthLink authLink = AuthLink(
    getToken: () => token,
 );`